# i don't know how to make smoke particles in blender render

Tags: particles, smoke-simulation

I'm trying to create an object that emits red smoke from it and i can't find a way to create colored smoke(or ANY smoke). I'm new to this so I don't know how to use Blender too well, can someone please help me? also I'm sorry if the tags are wrong or something (I'm new to this site too).

Comment: You can use the Blender Smoke renderer [link](https://www.blender.org/manual/physics/smoke/index.html) OR set up a particule system that will emit planes that are textured for that purpose (clouds texture in color/alpha channels plus multiply a circular blend in alpha factor)

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5951/can-i-influence-the-direction-in-which-fire-and-smoke-dissolve. Find some tutorials about smoke setup in Blender like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oSiV5gg_lCs) for beginning. You can create particle system which will control emitting smoke *or* emit smoke directly from mesh.

Answer (score -1):

You click on the header bar then click on object(note: object, not object mode). Go to quick effects then quick smoke

Comment: Welcome to the site :) Your answer is being flagged as low-quality. Is it possible you could elaborate a bit? Perhaps add a screenshot?